# Dear gods, is there any way to roll back the Ux on the user pages?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Apparently the new UX design stresses less information on the page, and more scrolling around looking for it. I suspect this is a decision driven by the type of corporate mindset that assumes a Ux that has not changed lately must be a problem.

Is this execrable gob of shite revertible, or do we need to just wallow in the stink of it?

Comment: Diamond moderators and users don't have any control over the SE software itself, which is the origin of this change. You could ask this question on meta.SE, but the tenor and language of the question would probably be unwelcome.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the reminder, @Sycorax.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't an issue that stats.SE users & moderators can fix, and the tenor of the question is emotionally charged and provocative. It's closer to a complaint than a topic of discussion, or solicitation of a way to convince SE, inc. improve the Ux.